# I want to change a CSS value to a negative number but when I do the jquery stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").delay(1000).animate({
        top: (0 px),
        opacity: 1,
    }, 700, function() {});
});
```

I want to change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").delay(1000).animate({
        top: (-50 px),
        opacity: 1,
    }, 700, function() {});
});
```

but when I do the jquery stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the error console. Using a "non-negative" `top: (50 px)` - and the shown `top: (0 px)` - would have failed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-50` instead of `-50 px`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").delay(1000).animate({
    top: -50,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 700, function() {});
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="position:relative;opacity:0">dghdghfdhf</h1>
```

Comment: @AdamOgden : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 top: "-50px"
```

instead of

```
 top: (-50px)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting string `"-50px"` for `(-50px)`

Answer (score 1):

you missed putting it in quotes..
try

```
top: "-50px",
```